# Alternating Series Error Estimation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If I want to find the approximate sum of an alternating series such that its error value is less than some arbitrary value $E$, and I also know that the $n + 1$th term of this series $b_{n+1} < E$, do I need to sum up $n$ terms or $n+1$ terms?

Comment: $n$ terms would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your series is of the form $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nb_n$ with $b_n>0$ and $b_{n+1}<b_n$ for all $n$ (this is essential) then by [Leibnitz criterion for alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) you have 
$$
\left|S-\sum_{n=1}^k(-1)^nb_n\right|\leq b_{k+1}.
$$
So if $b_{k+1}<E$ then you know that the sum up to $k$ approaches $S$ with error less than $E$.